# How to connect to ZOOM API

Tags: python, zoom-sdk

for a small project, I'm looking to connect to zoom API which means: I want to use as input the audio, video, and chat. and do something with this input in my program.
What I've done so far:
I was able to connect audio to my program with python SpeechRecognition library, and Virtual cable.
My next step: Somehow use get the chat and do something with it and the video.
I write my program in python but I'm open to other ways.
Thank you!

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import keyboard
import os
import time


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        try:
            audio = r.listen(source, timeout=2)
        except sr.WaitTimeoutError as e:
            return "None"
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Unable to Recognizing your voice.")
        return "None"
    return query


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()

    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
//dosomething with query
```